# Android: two sizes of View: measured one and drawing one. How to set drawing one?

Tags: android, view

The citation from `View` [reference](http://goo.gl/GGUza):

> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view
>   actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These
>   dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see
>   `Layout` for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by
>   calling `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`.
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes
>   drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual
>   size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These
>   values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width
>   and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling `getWidth()`
>   and `getHeight()`.

Well, i can set the measured size in `onMeasure(int, int)` by `setMeasuredDimension(int, int)`, but how can i set another one, drawing size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is set in the `onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)` method when you determine the left, top, right, bottom dimensions of the layout.  When you call `layout(int, int, int, int)` or `super.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)`, the `getHeight()` and `getWidth` properties will be set.